# Rails where not in array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have some posts that each has many tags.

I need to create a query that matches against the posts that are not having the exact tags as in an array.

Also it should return all the posts that are not having tags at all with that query.

Here is what I tried:

```
  query = posts.joins('LEFT JOIN post_tags ON post.id = post_tags.post_id')
  no_tags = ['test', 'test1']
  query = query.where('post_tags.name NOT IN (?) OR post_tags.name IS ?', no_tags, nil) if no_tags
```

This gives me all the posts that are having no tags at all which is correct, also it gives me the posts that haven't the tags specified, **and no other tags**, which is also correct.

The problem is that if a post has **multiple** tags, say `test, another`, it returns it in the query, which is not the behaviour I want.

I need to filter these posts out, if a post has a tag that is in the array, whether another tags are included or not.

Example:

```
post1 has tag `test`
post2 has tag `another`
post3 has tags `test, another`
post4 has no tags
```

It should return:

```
[post2, post4]
```

But now it returns:

```
[post2, post3, post4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining a `post` that has two tags with `post_tags` returns two rows.

```
post_name   post_tag
test3       test
test3       another
```

You should now understand why 'test3' is included in your result. The check is done for each row result and one of them passes as valid.

Consider doing something like

```
no_tags = ['test', 'test1']
query = query.where('post.id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_tags WHERE name IN (?))', 
  no_tags) if no_tags
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should select all posts which have `no_tags`, call it `excluded_posts`. Then you make a query to get all posts that different from the `excluded_posts`. Here is Rail code example:

```
excluded_post_ids = PostTag.where.not(name: no_tags).select(:post_id)
expected_post = Post.where.not(id: excluded_post_ids)
```

Comment: I don't think this is efficient at all, it will query on whole table.

Comment: in first query, Rails does not load all object into memory, it just generate query string. it is lazy loading mechanism